# Bash script that kills other instances of itself if they're running

Tags: bash

So, I want to make a bash script, and I'm going to have it run on boot, but I'd like to update the script if I need to and run it without a reboot, so what I want to do is make the script check if there is any other instances of it running when it is loaded, and terninate any instances of the script other than itself. I want it to check instances of bash and get the path of the scripts that are being ran and kill any instances of scripts that have the same path name as it's own. How can I do this?

Example: If I am in directory /foo/bar and I run the script ../tball/script.sh, it will kill any instances of bash that are running the script /foo/tball/script.sh if they exist.

Comment: Ah, me and Ricardo argued for best answer, but Eduardo doesn't pick an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basis

```
    kill_others() {
       local mypid=$$    # capture this run's pid
    
       declare -a pids=($(pgrep -f ${0##*/})  # get all the pids running this script
    
       for pid in ${pids[@]}; do              # cycle through all pids except this one
          [[ $pid -ne $mypid ]] && kill $pid  # kill the other pids
          sleep 1                             # give time to complete
       done
    }
    
    declare -i count=0
    while [[ $(pgrep -f ${0##*/}|wc -l) -gt 1 ]]; do
       kill_others
       ((++count))
       if [[ $count -gt 10 ]]; then
          echo "ERROR: can't kill pids" >&2
          exit 1
       fi
    done
```

Comment: Why not just call `kill_others` and avoid the test of `[[ $(pgrep -f ${0##*/}|wc -l) -gt 1 ]]` altogether? If `mypid` is the only `pid` nothing will happen regardless of the count. Either way, I like your approach.

Comment: If you have a process that is hung, a normal kill may not be able to kill it-- needing a `kill -9`.  However, you don't want to default to a `kill -9` as it won't allow any cleanup actions to occur.

Comment: Agreed. After `sleep 1`, you could check if the PID is still active -- then call `kill -9` if it remains. Too bad there isn't a way to call `killall` first (but the same name prevents that...)

Comment: Having the script appending its PID to a known location and running `kill $(< /run/script.pid)` before is easier.  Too much shell code for something so simple.

Comment: @RicardoBranco, the error checking should/could be wrapped around your way of killing it.  If you aren't concerned with hung pids, then it's simplier.  I write things to report on errors.

Comment: Simple.  Docker does something like this: `kill $(< /run/script.pid) ; sleep 10 ; kill -9 $(< /run/script.pid)`

Comment: Docker may, your answer does not. :-)

Comment: The script simply does not work as written. Most obvious is of course the call to "kill_outhers" in the first line of the while loop. But also the line: declare pids=($(pgrep -f ${0##*/} - two start parentheses that are never closed. One of them should probably be a left curly brace.

Sadly I don't know enough bash to fix it, perhaps the author would care to?

Comment: I got notified for an answer from 6 years ago-- typos fixed.  @Acebone

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is a file containing the PID of the process in a volatile filesystem like this:

```
echo $$ > /run/script.pid
```

You could refine it further by checking if that PID exists with:

```
if [ ! -d /proc/$(< /run/script.pid) ] ; then
   rm /run/script.pid
fi
```

In your script you should have something like this, to remove the file on exit or if it receives a signal that kills the process:

```
trap "rm -f /run/script.pid" EXIT INT QUIT TERM
```

EDIT: Or you could append the PID to a well known pathname and kill all instances of the script with something like this before saving the PID:

```
kill $(< /run/script.pid) ; sleep 10 ; kill -9 $(< /run/script.pid)
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the OP, they want a new script, to kill the old ones.  This is what I'd implement to not run a new script if an old one was running.

Comment: If the script is well coded, there's no need to kill other instances of it.

Comment: The OP said specifically that he wants to be able to update the script ("but I'd like to update the script if I need to and run it without a reboot") and start it again killing the previous ones.  Well coded also means meeting requirements you don't like.

Comment: In this case, the script should append its PID to a well known pathname so a simple kill $(< cat /run/script.pids) will suffice.

Comment: Files are mutable, and are less reliable than checking the process snapshot.  I use lock files, but I'd not do it in this case.  Checking the ps is easier to wrap troubleshooting around, and more reliable.  There's no reason to do it another way.

Comment: PID files in volatile filesystems are something that all well-coded daemons create.  Just check /run/*.pid and /run/user/$UID/*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144280/discussion-between-sainthax-and-ricardo-branco).